# IBM WebSphere Solr search crashing site

Tags: solr, websphere, websphere-7, websphere-8, websphere-commerce

Currently using IBM websphere I just installed APAR fix pack 8 and switched to a different database. Local host works but now products are not populated on the site correctly and the site just crashes when I click on one of the few products that are showing.

This is the error right after I click product. I also see this error a lot "null: CWXFS2003E: Cannot process search request."

```
4/7/16 10:02:20:058 EDT] 0000002a SolrCore      E org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing value only works for numeric or STRING types
    at org.apache.lucene.search.SortField.setMissingValue(SortField.java:208)
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.internal.server.services.search.component.solr.SolrSearchMultipleQueryComponent.process(SolrSearchMultipleQueryComponent.java:1243)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:214)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1916)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:780)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:427)
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.internal.server.services.search.servlet.solr.SolrSearchDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrSearchDispatchFilter.java:100)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:217)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:80)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:965)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:508)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:878)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:454)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:516)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:307)
```

Comment: is there more to the stack? could the issue be that you have switched to a different database?

Comment: The database works for everyone else's local environment just not my local environment

Comment: Has everyone else installed fix pack 8 as well?

Comment: No I am the first one to try the update and see how it works out Are you aware of this new update causing any issues such as this?

Comment: I am not aware of any issue like this.  If you have any additional information (i.e. the rest of the stack, and code examples) please update your question with more info.  Not much to go off of right now.  Otherwise, I would suggest opening a PMR with IBM.

Answer (score 0):

While inspecting the changes made to SolrSearchMultipleQueryComponent, I can see that the JR55662 (also included in cumulative fix #3) disables sortMissingValue in extension index. 
So, this should resolve the issue.

JR55662 should have low risk since its purpose is to add logging statement, as described in:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1JR55662

So install cumulative fix #3 or ask IBM to deliver the single APAR in the link